# Expected behavior of IEnumerable member of class when items are added via interface function

Tags: c#, addition, ienumerable, behavior

I have a class, which has an IEnumerable. On this class there is an interface function to `Add` new items to this IEnumerable collection. The way this interface `Add` function works is by first converting the current collection to a list, adding a new one, and converting it back to an IEnumerable. Now the instance of the IEnumerable has changed, and all references to this IEnumerable member of the class are 'decoupled'.

Is this simply a matter of choice? Or is it desired behavior to keep the IEnumerable references coupled?

Are there coding guidelines for such behavior?

See the example code below which demonstrates the decoupling behavior:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var factory = new Factory();
            factory.AddPackageId(1);
            var referenceToPackageIds = factory.PackageIds;
            factory.AddPackageId(1);
            Console.WriteLine("referenceToPackageIds contains {0} packages.", referenceToPackageIds.Count());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Factory
    {
        public IEnumerable<int> PackageIds
        {
            get
            {
                if (_PackageIds == null)
                {
                    _PackageIds = new List<int>();
                }
                return _PackageIds;
            }
            set
            {
                //Do some sanity checks here... but left out for brevity.
                _PackageIds = value;
            }
        }

        private IEnumerable<int> _PackageIds; 

        public void AddPackageId(int packageId)
        {
            var list = PackageIds.ToList();
            list.Add(packageId);
            PackageIds = list.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I count three question marks in the question.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Whether the demonstrated behavior of the IEnumerable is expected behavior, and whether there are coding guidelines for behavioral questions like these.

Comment: `_PackageIds` is private, so you can implement it entirely how you want and what suits your class's internal usage best. I would declare it as `(I)List<int>` instead of the useless `.ToList()` and `.ToArray()` copying upon adding.

Comment: @CodeCaster I am not the owner of the code. I agree with what you say, but that's another aspect of this piece of code.

Comment: Then what is your question? What **behavior** are you talking about?

Comment: Someone could earn points with an answer that discusses what the expected behavior is, with the why or even references to Microsoft or whatever coding standards there might be out there that concern this issue.

Comment: @CodeCaster Do you understand C# object references (or C++ pointers?). Because that is what my question is related to.

Comment: Do you mean you don't want users of this class to have access to the internal list? You don't have to declare the private field as IEnumerable for that, just use ToList() in the public get.

Comment: @CodeCaster You totally miss the point. What is it that you don't understand in the following sentence: `is it desired behavior to keep the IEnumerable references coupled`?

Comment: Can you rewrite that sentence? Can you explain what _you_ mean by "behavior" and "coupled"? I don't think your _"all references to this IEnumerable member of the class are 'decoupled'"_ makes sense. Your class needs a collection it can add to, so IEnumerable is not the right interface to use.

Comment: @CodeCaster He's not asking about the internal behaviour of the class, he's asking about the interface. If a class exposes an `IEnumerable<T>` property and an `Add(T)` method, and you take a copy of the `IEnumerable<T>` reference and then call `Add(t)`, would you expect your copy of the `IEnumerable<T>` reference to now contain `t`?

Comment: @Rawling if that is the question, that has nothing to do with interfaces (replacing `IEnumerable` with `List` in the code shown won't change anything) and ["coupling" in the software design sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)), in which context those terms are generally used. This greatly adds to the confusion, but thanks for this insight.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is merely a special case of a more general question: if an object exposes a method whose return type provides a read-only view of something, is the returned view expected to be:

1. A view of an immutable snapshot, which will not change even if the object does.
2. A "live" read-only view of the object, which will show any changes made to the object
3. A view which will reflect the current state of the object as long as the object is not modified, but makes no promises with regard to behavior if it is.

In many cases, #3 will be the cheapest one for the method to provide, and it will fit most callers' needs.  Callers should not expect a method to return #1 or #2 unless the documentation of the method explicitly specifies which; callers which are prepared for #3 will be satisfied with any of the above.

It's too bad the creators of Java and .NET were so opposed to Hungarian notation, since distinctions like the above would otherwise represent an excellent use for it.  If a method returns `IEnumerable<T>`, nothing in the type system will indicate which of the above kinds of thing it returns, but such information is often vital when trying to write efficient and correct code.  I would suggest that you affirmatively decide whether you wish to promise callers that the object you return will never change, or whether to explicitly refrain from making such a promise.  Making the promise will allow some callers to be more efficient (since callers that want a snapshot will be able to use the returned object directly, rather than having to copy the contents to a new immutable object) but may compel future versions of the class to copy the contents of a mutable object for the purpose of returning them, when it would otherwise be able to simply return a read-only wrapper.